# I was commiting my change to a repo of github but it was showing error and told me to create gpg key of github

Tags: reactjs, github, repository, push, commit

[it's the message after I commit my all staged changes in git repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSpwK.jpg)

Command output after clicking on show command output of above shown image is as follows :

> git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file - --verbose --signoff -S
> gpg: skipped "Chanchal14-creator chanchalbaghel60@gmai.com": No secret key
> gpg: signing failed: No secret key
> error: gpg failed to sign the data
> fatal: failed to write commit object